# UIWebView ScaleToFit Not Working for Local Image Path

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I made a UIWebview to show a local image. Here is my code:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath];
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
webView.delegate = self;
webView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];

NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];
[webView loadRequest: req];
webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

When I open a large image, it does not fit in the screen.

same this picture >>> [image]

Thank you. (sorry for my english not good)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How large is your image?

If I remember correctly, the default minimum-zoom of a webpage is 0.25 with UIWebView. Because of this, you cannot fit an image larger than 1280pixels on iPhone with the default settings.

If that is your issue, you can solve the problem by loading the image in your own HTML document, and define the viewport yourself in that document through the viewport metatag (for example ), see https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html

If the problem is not the size of the image, you should check the size of your UIWebView. It may have an incorrect frame for some reason.

Comment: i use html string it work for me.

 NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                            @"<html><meta name='viewport' content='maximum-scale=20.0'/><body><img src='%@' width='965'></body></html>",url];

 [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];